# selectableItemBackground in AppCompat v. 23.4.0

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm using selectableItemBackground attribute as CardView foreground.

After upgrading to libraries v. 23.4.0, I see the following when I tap on the card:

[image: wrong resource?]

It seems that it points to wrong resource:

```
<style name="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Platform.AppCompat">
....
<item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/abc_item_background_holo_dark</item>
...
</style>
```

Is there a workaround (excluding rolling back to previous AppCompat libs?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with your appcompat 23.4, please try to downgrade your gradle plugin to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

Latest gradle plugin looks like having some bugs.